# Not able to understand why i cant run ping command inside container built from dotnetcore sdk base image with docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, debian, .net-core-3.1

1. my docker file is

   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1

   COPY . .
2. My current directory consists of
   [image]
3. when i try to run commands like ping i get
   [image]

4. The main problem i am trying to solve is that,am unable to connect to private feed (artifactory) from inside container , any pointers will help.

Comment: I'm able to `ping www.google.com` after running `docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 /bin/bash`, so it seems to be some problem on your end (i.e the host machine). How are you running the container? Is the host Windows or Linux (looks like Windows from the screenshot)

Comment: Host is windows . Running a Linux container . I am in corporate environment if that helps .

Comment: Are there any network setting i can check to see if something is wrong ?

Comment: I'm afraid there's not much information to go on here. Try different machines, different networks (your phone's mobile network with tethering instead of corporate maybe, if that's allowed), different operating system (do you have a Linux machine available you can try it on?). Does rebooting the machine help? etc

Comment: as soon as i switched of vpn, ping works.

Comment: so now i think the questions becomes how do i tell my container to use the proxy settings? Please correct if i am thinking in the right direction?

Comment: VPN and proxy are two different things, and it seems you are confusing them. Moreover, solving this probably depends on a lot of unknown things such as what VPN software are you using and how exactly it's set up. VPN + Docker + Windows sounds like a nightmare to me and is beyond my grasp, can't help you further.